# How to combine tablenames if equal and count columns SQL

Tags: sql, count, schema

```
SELECT Tabname, Colname 
  FROM Systemcatalog 
 WHERE Tabschema = 'X'
```

Giving me

```
Tabname, Colname
A         X1
A         Y1
A         Z1
B         X2
C         X3
C         Y2
C         Z2
...
```

But What I need is:

```
Tabname, Colnum
A         3
B         1
C         3
...
```

so counting all columns for each table putting it in a new column and at the same time delete double elements in tabname.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by` and `count`.

```
SELECT Tabname
    , count(*) as Colnum 
FROM Systemcatalog 
GROUP BY Tabname
WHERE Tabschema = 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` to get the aggregate count.

```
SELECT Tabname, count(Colname) as total_columns
FROM Systemcatalog 
WHERE Tabschema = 'X'
GROUP BY Tabname
```